# jQuery: How to select text between two closed html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to wrap the intro/help text in html document using jQuery.It is not inside any tag but between two closed html tags.

Please see attached code snippet for example. the 2nd end tag can also be other than `<p>`.

```js
var txtHelp = jQuery('b.page-title').nextUntil('p').text();
console.log(txtHelp);

//jQuery('b.page-title').nextUntil('p').text().wrap("<p />");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b class="page-title"><h4>System Log</h4><hr class="text-primary"></b>
How to select this text and wrap it in new P-Tag
<p align="center">This can by any html tag</p>
```

Comment: `$('b.page-title')[0].nextSibling.textContent`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **[`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** method not selects textnodes.

You can get the text node by **[`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)** property of node and get text content by **[`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** property of text node.

```js
var txtHelp = jQuery('b.page-title')[0] // get the dom object
  .nextSibling // get the text node next to it
  .textContent; // get text content
console.log(txtHelp);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b class="page-title"><h4>System Log</h4><hr class="text-primary"></b>
How to select this text and wrap it in new P-Tag
<p align="center">This can by any html tag</p>
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :** If you want to wrap the element by a `p` tag then do it like.

```js
$( // wrap by jquery to convert to jQuery object
  $('b.page-title')[0] // get the dom element also you can use `get(0)`
  .nextSibling // get the textnode which is next to it
).wrap('<p/>'); //  wrap the element by p tag
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b class="page-title"><h4>System Log</h4><hr class="text-primary"></b>
How to select this text and wrap it in new P-Tag
<p align="center">This can by any html tag</p>
```

---

**UPDATE 2 :** If it contains `br` tag and you want to include it as a text then do something tricky using **[`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)** method.

```js
var get = false;

$($('b.page-title')
  .parent() // get it's parent
  .contents() // get all children node including text node
  .filter(function() {
    if ($(this).is('b.page-title')) {
      get = true; // if element is 'b.page-title' then set flag true , we need to get element from here
      return false // return false that we don't need the 'b.page-title'
    }
    if ($(this).is('p')) // check element is `p`, that we need to get element uptop tag
      get = false; // update flag
    return get; // return the flag for filtering
  })).wrapAll('<p/>'); // use wrapAll to wrap all elements withing single tag
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b class="page-title"><h4>System Log</h4><hr class="text-primary"></b>
How to select this text
<br/>and wrap it in new P-Tag
<p align="center">This can by any html tag</p>
```

Comment: Thanks this completely works..
But there what is the signiicance of [0] here, i found it not working without it.
also what if the contents has some <br> in it?
`How to select this text and wrap it in new P-Tag<br><br>
new line<br> new line`
i used `jQuery('b.page-title').nextUntil(':not(br)').remove();` this before above code but only wrapping 1st line.

Comment: @AmitShah :  __1)__ `[0]` for getting dom object from jQuery object  __2)__ Updated the answer please check it

Answer (score 1):

For a pure jQuery approach, you can try this:

```
var contents = $('b.page-title').contents(),
    textNodes = contents.filter(function() { return this.nodeType === 3; });

console.log(textNodes[0].textContent);
```

See [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)